# On the definition of a filter: Isn't $\emptyset$ a subset of any set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Beginning my study of nonstandard analysis, I have found this definition of a filter U on a set J, where A, B are subsets of J:

1. Proper filter: $\emptyset \not\in U$,
2. Finite intersection property: If $A, B\in U$, then $A\cap B\in U$,
3. Superset property: If $A\in U$ and $A\subseteq B$, then $B\in U$.

It seems to me that (3) contradicts (1), since any set in the filter has ∅ as a subset. Is this untrue? If so, could someone please explain how ∅ isn't a subset of any set?

Comment: (3) does not state that if $A \in U$, then any *subset* of $A$ is in $U$, but insted than any "super-set" of $A$ is in $U$. Thus, no contradiction at all...

Answer (score 2):

The empty set is a subset of every other set. The item (3) does not contradict (1), for what it says is that a filter is closed under **super**sets and not under **sub**sets.

Answer (score 1):

Were $\emptyset$ to be in the filter then every subset of the base space is in the filter as well by the superset property.

Comment: The neighborhoods of a  given point in a topological space form a filter.